# Pattern printing with arrays/tuples

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

So I'm trying to do this

You will be given a positive integer n > 0 and you will construct a pattern that is made up of n rows:
• Row 0 contains 1 number—the number 1

• Each row is one longer than the one before and follows the pattern that ensues

So if variable `n:int` = 4, the output would be

```
[1]
[1,2]
[2,3,5]
[5,7,10,15]
```

The number in the current array is added to the number immediately above it in the previous array and appended at the end of the current array. Also when starting a new array the last element of the previous array is considered as the first element of the current array.
I apologize if my question is unclear, but I hope after the example and explanation I provided, the question is clearer now.
Here is my code:

```
def append(n: int):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        return(x,x+1)
    print(append(n))
```

When I put n = 4, it doesnt seem to work, what's the problem here?

Comment: Your indentation is off; can you please edit the question to make sure your code block is representing the indention of your actual code correctly? That said, `return` ends the function immediately. And `(x, x+1)` would never make the pattern you show (for that matter, you're not being sufficiently clear on what rules produce the pattern shown).

Comment: currently your function is just immediately returning the tuple `(1, 2)` from the first iteration of the loop. Do you intend to get a list of the lists above or how do you expect these multiple elements to be returned? What does the expected output look like for other inputs (e.g. 1 through 5)?

Comment: if n = 5, then the expected output would be                                                                   
[1]
[1,2]
[2,3,5]
[5,7,10,15]                                                                                                                                [7,12,19,29,44]

Comment: If this is an assignment then you should probably just include the actual assignment text because your description of the requirement is vague and ambiguous.

Comment: @DaveShah So your desired output is a list but you return a tuple and say tuple in the question. Tuples are immutable, so you can't append to them. I think you need to clarify if you want a list or a tuple.

Comment: Also.. your defined output and the description seem like two different things. The description seems like it's asking for the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I have updated my question. Hopefully you understand it:)

Comment: if anyone can figure out a problem with the code, please correct me by writing your desired change in the answers section plzzz :()

Comment: How is the output calculated?

Comment: @helpneeded so the start of the list is always [1], and then for 'n' lines it will add the number directly below it and append the number to the end of the list and repeat this step for n lines. I provided an example in my question as well for clarification:)

Comment: @Dave Shah all I know now is that the list starts with 1 and then every line a number is added. No clues on which numbers are added though. Now I am looking at your example trying to figure it out: [1] - alright got that, [1,2] - okay so simply 1+1 = 2, expecting [1,2,3] next but no - [2,3,5] - hmmm 2+3=5? - next one [5,7,10,15] - ?? Do you now understand why I am asking?

Comment: so its like, [1], [1,2] now the last number in the previous list becomes the starting number of the new list so [2,x,x] and for x in the list, we take the starting number 2, and add it with the corresponding number in the previous list, so the output order is [1],[1,2] and then it will return [2, (2+1, which is the same corresponding number to 2 in the previous list)  and ends with 3, since 2 + 3 = 5.

Comment: Then how come after [5,7,10,15] it does not start with 15? in case n=5 which you commented above

Comment: @helpneeded it does actually. Maybe I just wrote wrong.. its (15, 20, 27, 37,52). Hopefully u can find my mistake and correct my code:)

Comment: Your code obviously does not do it in any kind of way, I propose you try it yourself...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code will return the pattern you want to show. Here's a little code I wrote to print that pattern but there are two loops running, if you could optimize that you could do it or else use the code just as it is.

```
n=4
arr=[1]
brr = [1]
print(brr)
for i in range(0,n-1):
  brr = arr[i:]
  for k in range(0,len(arr)):
    brr.append(arr[k]+brr[k])
  arr = brr
  print(brr)
```

Comment: can you do it using tuples?? i dont know if that is possible or not but yea if it is possible to use tuples, can you please edit your answer using tuples??

Comment: @DaveShah Actually values in tuples cannot be change once initialized (as much as I know ). If you still want to use tuples you will have to create a new tuple every time you initialize(store) the new values. So for n = 4 you will need 4 tuples and so on, basically n tuples, taking up lots of computational space.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
def func(n):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(n):
        if i == 0:
            mylist.append([1])
        else:
            mylist.append(createnewlist(mylist[i-1]))
    return mylist
                        
def createnewlist(a):
    newlist = [] 
    for i in range(len(a)+1):
        if i == 0:
            newlist.append(a[len(a)-1])
        else:
            value = a[len(a)-1]
            for m in range(i):
                value += a[m]
            newlist.append(value)
    return newlist

print(func(6))
```

Comment: is there a shorter way to do it?? if there is, can you please edit it? Thank you :)

Comment: like can u combine createnewlist(a) and func(a) into one single function. It would help a lot. Thank u very much ")

Comment: pls try to not be mean when ur interacting with ppl online. I'm asking you because I do not know how to do it, and for the 'im not ur slave' thing. What I did was ask you to help me, not command you to do it for me... please look at the entire context before deciding to comment something rude.

Comment: calm down please, I'm just saying that you should try to do it yourself and if you get stuck you can ask another question but questions like this usually get closed because I actually probably did your homework and if you want it to be coded in another way you should really put in some work yourself