# How can I append a new number to my list for every new line for my code?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Side note: In case you might be wondering, the owner of this account is the same person as the 'Dave Shah' account, who posted the same question. I'm asking this question again on my second account(this one) because I was getting rude comments because I didnt know how to solve things..

link to THAT post: [How can I append a new number to my list for every new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811478/how-can-i-append-a-new-number-to-my-list-for-every-new-line)

So my real question is down below....

So I'm trying to do this

You will be given a positive integer n > 0 and you will construct a pattern that is made up of n rows: • Row 0 contains 1 number—the number 1

• Each row is one longer than the one before and follows the pattern that ensues

In case you dont see a connection between each number and the number on the left of the original number and the number above the number on the left. Also the first number of each new list is the last number of the previous list.

So if variable n:int = 4, the output would be

```
[1]
[1,2]
[2,3,5]
[5,7,10,15]
```

Here is my code:

```
def append(n: int):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        return(x,x+1)
    print(append(n))
```

When I put n = 4, it doesnt seem to work, what's the problem here?

Comment: Do you want to print it in `list` form or just the pattern?

Comment: hey, thx for taking ur time off to help me. Yessir, I would like to make it in list form.

Comment: `return(x,x+1)` in your code **returns** `tuple` and only **one** result. You must use `yield`  to return multiple lines. Your pattern is: `[1],[1,2],[2,3,5],[5,7,10,15]` so I don't get how do you want to skip the numbers, i.e:-  ***4,6,8,9...*** are missing.

Comment: okay so whats happening is... we start with 1. that is always true, and then we add one to it, and then append the resulting number into a new line of list, and then the appended number is the beginning of the new list in the line below and then we add the number directly above it and that gives us the new number on the right

Comment: its kinda hard to explain sorry, but if u have a look at the example I provided in my original question, see the connection between the number on the right and the number on the left and the number above the number on the left. Also the first number of each new list is the last number of the previous list.

Answer (score 1):

**If you take [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69812895/12731745) and make it a little bit shorter, you can write:**

```
def func(n):
    arr=[1]
    yield arr
    for i in range(n-1): 
        for k in range(len(arr)): 
            arr.append(arr[k]+arr[i + k]) 
        arr = arr[i:] 
        yield arr
```

**You can now use this function like:**

```
for i in func(4):
    print(i)
# Output:
# [1]
# [1,2]
# [2,3,5]
# [5,7,10,15]
```

***As it is a Generator***

**Edit: If you just want to output it in the function, you just have to replace yield with print() like @Bibhav said:**

```
def func(n):
    arr=[1]
    print(arr)
    for i in range(n-1): 
        for k in range(len(arr)): 
            arr.append(arr[k]+arr[i + k]) 
        arr = arr[i:] 
        print(arr)
```

**Edit: If you would want to use the yield approach in conjunction with something like list() you should replace `yield arr` with `yield arr[:]` or list(arr) to copy that list because otherwise changing 'arr' inside of the function can cause Problems with yield.**

```
# Changed 'arr' to 'arr[:]'
def func(n):
    arr=[1]
    yield arr[:]
    for i in range(n-1): 
        for k in range(len(arr)): 
            arr.append(arr[k]+arr[i + k]) 
        arr = arr[i:] 
        yield arr[:]
```

**Then you can use it like:**

```
print(list(func(4)))
# Output:
# [[1],[1,2],[2,3,5],[5,7,10,15]]
```

**Edit: If you would want to use return, do:**

```
# You still need to have 'arr[:]'
def func(n):
    ret=[]
    arr=[1]
    ret.append(arr[:])
    for i in range(n-1): 
        for k in range(len(arr)): 
            arr.append(arr[k]+arr[i + k]) 
        arr = arr[i:] 
        ret.append(arr[:])
    return ret
```

Comment: hey, thank u for ur reply, I just wanted to know is there a way to fit the 'for i in func(4): print (i) into the original function??

Comment: You can use `print(arr)` instead of `yield arr` for that. So it will directly print when you call the function `func(4)`

Comment: when I say original function, I mean the function that you provided as a correction to mine... like the func(n) function

Comment: @Bibhav is right

Comment: If you meant to print it inside of the function you should replace yield with print(). If this is the case, i can edit my Answer.

Comment: Thank u very much :)

Comment: @Kumpelinus hey, one more question, so I tried to use 'return' instead of yield on your code but now the output only returns [1] and [1,2]... can you please explain like how to use return in your code as well??

Comment: @Bruffff I would rather use yield for that use case